# Nested object in array - object destructing es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I know you can do object destructing like: `const { item } = data;`

Also array destructing like: `const [ item ] = data;`

You can also do this in function params like: `const x = ({ item }) => item;`

And I've seen lots of questions and answers on it. However I haven't seen an example and a good explanation of nested objects in an array.

---

```
const test = [{ count: 1 }];

const [{ count }] = test;
```

I'd normally do:

```
const x = test[0];

const { count } = x;
```

It was only today while testing in codepen that I figured out you could destructor them both within the same assignment.

Could anyone explain what's going on when I'm doing `[{ count }]`? Because I'm doing array destructing with the `const [] = test` but I'm not destructing anything so that obviously fails. If I then `{ count }` within that I get the value out I want.

I can't break it down enough to understand how it's working. I'd assume `[] = test` is the same as `test[0]` then i do `{ count } = test[0]`. But I'd just like to understand how it's working more.

*I did have a look through some of the MDN docs and stuff but I can't find a good explanation on the above scenario I mentioned.*

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help when you see that `const [ , , { count }] = [{ apple: 1}, {pear: 5}, {count: 13}, {delta: 2}]` assigns 13 to `count`?

Comment: Rather `const [temp] = test, {count} = temp;`

Comment: Right! Thanks @Bergi see, i didn't know you could do `const [aVarName] = test;` and that will be the equivalent of `const aVarName = test[0];`. I thought You're always unpacking values and you can assign defaults but any value you pass into the `[]` it sees as a param to destructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nested destructuring can be confusing sometimes. You can always check on the [**Babel compiler**](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG0BQMYEg_YG8ZQBXMKALhgAYYBfAGhi21bbaIHcALAQwQBu8AE5UATPQYs8OQnBBReAG3H0W7dgF0A3BgyhIsNEVLlJMJkSgLl9TSjiIoeoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.3) to get the ES5 equivalent and understand how it works

So, this code:

```js
const test = [{ count: 0 }, { whatever: 1 }, { total: 2 }];
const [{ count }, , { total }] = test

console.log(count, total)
```

Gets trasnpiled to:

```
var count = test[0].count;
var total = test[2].total;
```

As you can see, `index = 1` item is [ignored (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) and we are only destructuring the `0`th and `2`nd index properties

Since, we are on the topic of destructuring array objects, this can be used in much more advanced ways. You can destructure an item at **any index** like this:

```js
const test = [{ count: 0 }, { count: 1 }, { count: 2 }];

const { 2: { count } } = test;

console.log(count)
```

This gets the count at index `2`. This code is equivalent to:

```
var count = test[2].count;
```

Note that, we are using `{}` here instead of `[]`. This instructs the compiler to get the `count` at the *key*: `2`. You can also get the `length` of the array using this type of destructuring:

```
const { length } = test; // same as test.length
```

You can make it even more dynamic with a [computed object property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring):

```js
const test = [{ count: 0 }, { count: 1 }, { count: 2 }];
const index = 2;

const { [index]: { count } } = test;

console.log(count)
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this! So it's pretty much syntactic sugar for `variable.key`. That's why you can do the length destructuring. I assume in that case, I can also destructor any method off the String object So I could pull out the `bind` or `prototype` methods also?

Comment: @TryingToLearnJS you can get them like that. But, do note that you cannot execute the `prototype` methods like this `forEach()` because they need a `this`. Length works because it's a property. You can however execute the static methods of array like this: `const {from, isArray } = Array; var arr = from({ length: 5 }) // returns an array of length 5;  isArray(arr) // returns true`

Answer (score 1):

It might make things easier if you think of Object & Array destructuring as the reverse operation of object & array creation:

```
 ({ key: value  } = // reverses building object with "key"
  { key: "test" }); // builds up object with "key"

 ([{ nested: value2 }] = // reverses building an array containing an object
  [{ nested: "test" }]); // builds up an array containing an object
```